Problem on Function of Prime Number.
Let $f:(1,\infty)\to(0,\infty)$ be a continuous function such that for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $f(n)$ is the smallest prime factor of $n$. Then which of the following is/are correct?
a) $lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ exists.
b) $lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ does not exists.
c) The set of solutions to the equation $f(x)=2024$ is finite.
d) The set of solutions to the equation $f(x)=2024$ is infinite.
$\textbf{My approach:}$ as the range set (for $n\in\mathbb{N}$) is $\{ 1,2,3,2,5,2,7,2,3,\cdots\}$ then $lim_{x\to\infty}$ does not exist.
but for $f(x)=2024$ the set of solutions is finite as range can never get the value 2024 so it is empty set and empty set is finite. But it is given that set of solution to $f(x)=2024$ is infinite.
Please do check my approach and provide solution

You haven't explained why you think  $f(x)=2024$ is impossible.  Sure, there is no natural number $n$ such that $f(n)=2024$, but nobody said $x$ had to be a natural number.  For instance, $2029$ is prime so $f(2029)=2029$.  But $f(2028)=2$ so....

Neither have you really explained the limit part.  In general, what you write is very vague.  Try to write out proper arguments.

@lulu no I'm asking how $f(x)=2024$ can have infinite solution, as you clearly mentioned $f(p)=p$ for prime numbers but for non prime numbers $f(n)=p$ where $p$ is smallest prime factor of $n$, the question is only what I have written, even I had doubt how this is possible that is the reason why I'm asking it.

I explained to you how to find one solution.  There has to be some real $x$ with $2028<x<2029$ such that $f(x)=2024$, by continuity.  You should be able to generalize this to show that there are infinitely many solutions.

Note that values like $f(2.5)$, $f(\sqrt{43})$ and $f(\pi)$ exist. We know next to nothing about what they are, but they exist.

@lulu ok as the function is continuous it must take $f(x)=2024$ for some non natural number $x$, but then it will have one solution, how to imagine having more than one solution? by any graph methods is this possible?

@Arthur Yes it is nice observation even I missed it at first, but then still $f(x)=2024$ solution set can be finite or infinite?

As I have said, look at the argument I used.   Suppose you had a bigger prime $p>2029$.  Think about the argument I wrote and try to apply it to $p$.

@lulu if I use that argument then the function will be formed by connecting the range set elements of natural numbers that graph is  like stock market graphs goes up and comes down is that possible?

Of course the function oscillates badly.  for any even natural number $n$ we have $f(n)=2$, but for any prime we have $f(p)=p$.    But nobody said this was a sensibly behaved function, just that it was continuous.  Simplest example would be linear interpolation between the values for natural numbers.  Perfectly continuous.

Does this answer your question? $f(n) =$ the smallest prime factor of $n$. Prove that the number of solutions to the equation $f(x) = 2016$. - found using an Approach0 search. Note in part (b) of this answer, you can replace $2017$ with the prime $2027$ to handle your value of $2024$ instead of its $2016$.
